# PHP check assoc array for key, if exists, raise value by 1

Tags: php

So this is what I have so far:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
            if (!array_keys($usersPerCity, $user->city)){
                $usersPerCity[]=[$user->city => 1];
            }else{
                $usersPerCity[$user->city] = ($usersPerCity[$user->city] + 1);
            }
        }
```

My +1 has 0 effect, and it just plainly creates city => 1 without addition.
How would I be able to aggregate the city that already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had it right in the `else` just do it the same way.  Also, this is not what `array_keys` is for, did you mean `array_key_exists`?  Anyway, just use `isset` and you can just increment `++`:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    if (!isset($usersPerCity[$user->city])){
        $usersPerCity[$user->city] = 1;
    } else {
        //$usersPerCity[$user->city] = ($usersPerCity[$user->city] + 1);
        $usersPerCity[$user->city]++;
    }
}
```

As of PHP 7.0 just extract the `city` from the array of objects and count the values:

```
$usersPerCity = array_count_values(array_column($users, 'city'));
```

Comment: it's ok, please explain to me why array_keys couldn't do that addition?

Comment: `array_keys` just extracts all of the keys into a new array, it makes no sense here. And the first time thru the loop the array doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Cadaver :)